# The rate of change of the distance between the tips of the hands of a clock

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The hands of a clock in some tower are approximately 5m and 2m in length. How fast is the distance between the tips of the hands changing at 9:00. (Hint: use law of cosines)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with? Have you tried applying the hint, or drawn a picture for this problem yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so using the law of cosines:

Given that the sides of the triangle are a, b and c, respectively. Also, their corresponding angles being A, B, and C, we find that:

$$a = 2, b = 5, C = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Also, at that instant, using the Pythagorean Theorem:

$$2^2 + 5^2 = c^2$$

$$c^2 = 29$$

$$c= \sqrt{29}$$

Law of cosines tell us that:

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*\cos C$$

We know that a and b are fixed (the lengths of the hands on the clock don't change) but C (the angle between them) constant changes.

Therefore, taking the derivative:

$$2c*c' = 0 + 0 + 2*2*5*\sin (C)*C' $$

Also, note that for a clock, the minute hand moves 6 degrees every minute, and the hour hand moves 0.5 degrees. So the angle between changes by 5.5 degrees every minute, or $\frac{11\pi}{360}$ radians.

Therefore:
$$2c*c' = 2*2*5*sin(\frac{\pi}{2})*\frac{11\pi}{360} $$

$$2*\sqrt{29}*c' = 2*2*5*1*\frac{11\pi}{360} $$

$$2*\sqrt{29}*c' = \frac{11\pi}{18} $$

$$c' = \frac{11\pi}{36\sqrt{29}} =  \frac{11\pi\sqrt{29}}{1044} \text{meters/min}$$

Comment: an upvote please?

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint! By the way, you made an error in the last step because 2*18=/=26, so the final answer is actually 11*PI*sqrt(29)/1044. I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I'll do it once I do get to 15 rep.

Comment: 2*18 = 36. I see what I did wrong. I'll update